# Python multiprocessing does nothing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Running from Visual Studio > Python console app...
OS is Windows 10.

Below simple code does not work.  The window stays up for a few seconds and then closes without printing anything on the window.

Please help me fix this.  It's been confusing and as I read from Internet so many people reported this, but I really appreciate if you provide me solution that can work on my environment.  Thanks.

```
import multiprocessing
import sys
import os

def foo():
    print('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    multiprocessing.set_executable(os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix, 'pythonw.exe'))

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo)
    p.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason for using the "set_executable" function? 
Try to look at the value of `sys.executable` is it different from the interpreter you would like to use? if it does, what is the path of the executable you want to use?

Try running it in the **cmd** using the following command `python <path_to_script.py>`

```py
import multiprocessing
import sys
import os

def foo():
    print('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    #multiprocessing.set_executable(os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix, 'pythonw.exe'))

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo)
    p.start()
```

Comment: I commented that 2 lines but it does not work for me.

Comment: Try running the python file directly in the cmd.exe, run: ```Python <path_to_file.py>```

Comment: My man!  Running absolutely fine now.  Thanks so much.  Glad to see this working finally.  Thank you everybody for such a quick replies.  Really appreciated it.

Comment: I have another unique problem about parallel processing.  Please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295683/python-multiprocessing-not-using-available-cores

Answer (score 0):

`pythonw.exe` is a GUI window, not a console. Where do you expect to see the "hello" you printed? If you want to make sure that the code in another process is actually run, write "hello" to some file, or open a window:

```
from tkinter import Tk

def foo():
    print('hello')
    t = Tk()
    t.mainloop()
```

or

```
from pathlib import Path

def foo():
    Path("some_file.txt").write_text("hello")
```

Also call `p.join()` at the end to wait for the process to finish.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Added p.join() but still does not work.  I expect to see the output on console window which pops up when I hit F5 from VS.  The console window is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe"

Comment: You won't see the output in that console, because the other process launches pythonw, python window, that process doesn't have console.

Comment: This does not work.  It does not even create the file.  import multiprocessing
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path

def foo():
    Path("C:\some_file.txt").write_text("hello")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo)
    p.start()